# Problem using OpenCV in WSL, when opening windows

Tags: python, linux, opencv, computer-vision, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL, and when running some Python code with OpenCV that needs to open a different window, it throws an error.
This is the code:

```
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread("images/pic.jpg")
cv.imshow(0)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

And this is the error I get

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this 
problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable your environment for GUI application on WSL.

[Using the GUI for enabling Windows features](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Using_the_GUI_for_enabling_Windows_features)

> 1. Open the Start Menu and search Turn Windows features on or off
> 2. Select Windows Subsystem for Linux
> 3. Click OK
> 4. Restart your computer when prompted

Comment: Have you installed any qt version? Maybe you can try `install libqt5gui5`

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. As recommended by most people, I tried putting a symbolic link and installing new packages. I changed QT_PLUGIN_PATH, I exported AT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 also. Those options did not seem to work for me. I was on Windows 10 with WSL2, running OpenCV cv2.image which was not showing. Errors were said to be qt related (as stated by #josh merrian).

```
    qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
    qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
    This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this 
    problem.

    Available platform plugins are: xcb.
    
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Try running xeyes.

```
    sudo apt-get install x11-apps
    xeyes
```

Does it run? If not you may be having the same problem I had.

In my case, I learnt that in WSL2 we need to have an Xserver to deploy Ubuntu oriented graphical applications. I read about Xming and also VcSrv. I tried VcSrv and it worked for me.

See: https://www.stat.ipb.ac.id/agusms/index.php/2019/01/15/how-to-run-graphical-linux-applications-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10/

Hope this helps somebody out there. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade OpenCV, with the following command using pip

```
pip3 install --upgrade opencv-python==4.3.0.36
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu on WSL 2:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx
sudo apt-get install xdg-utils
```